# How do you sort endpoints in swagger with the minimal api .net 6

Tags: swagger, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I am trying to get the hang of swagger in minimal API. I have the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(setup => setup.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo()
{
    Description = "An api that will change your life for ever",
    Title = "Alert Api",
    Version = "v1",
    Contact = new OpenApiContact()
    {
        Name = "Grundfos",
        Url = new Uri("https://grundfos.com")
    }
}));
WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//Map endpoints
app.MapGet("/alerts", async () => Results.Ok());
app.MapGet("/profiles", async () => Results.Ok());
```

this gives a swagger UI looking like this:

[image: Swagger interface]

My question is: How do you sort the endpoints to be under a headline called "alerts" and "profiles"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are after is something called `Tags` in swagger.

You can add `WithTags` at the end of your mapping, like so:

```
//Map endpoints
app.MapGet("/alerts", async () => Results.Ok()).WithTags("Alerts");
app.MapGet("/profiles", async () => Results.Ok()).WithTags("Profiles");
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

---

Alternatively you can also take another approach by configuring the `AddSwaggerGen` method.

In there you can take the first segment of the URL endpoint and use that as the tag name.

For example, the endpoints `alerts` and `alerts/delete` will both be placed in a section called `alerts`.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.TagActionsBy(d =>
    {
        var rootSegment = d.RelativePath?
            .Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Home";
        return new List<string> { rootSegment! };
    });
})


//Map endpoints without 'WithTags`
app.MapGet("/alerts", async () => Results.Ok());
app.MapGet("/alerts/delete", async () => Results.Ok());
app.MapGet("/profiles", async () => Results.Ok());
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
Found out my self and was about to post the exact same answer, you were just a minute faster :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of related endpoints and you want to group them in one tag `SomethingEndpoints`, you can do it by creating a static class named `SomethingEndpoints` and defining an extension method `MapSomethingEndpoints()` as follows.

**Notes:**

- The automatically added tags are only available when passing method `Job`.
- Passing `(int y) => Job(y)` or `(int z) => z` does not. You need to attach `WithTags()` manually in this case.
- I don't know whether it is a feature by design or a bug!

**SomethingEndpoints.cs**

```
static class SomethingEndpoints
{
    public static void MapSomethingEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        var group = routes.MapGroup("/api/v1/job");

        group.MapGet("/{x:int}", Job);// no need WithTags!
        group.MapGet("/{y:int}", (int y) => Job(y)).WithTags(nameof(SomethingEndpoints));
        group.MapGet("/{z:int}", (int z) => z).WithTags(nameof(SomethingEndpoints));
    }

    static int Job(int x) => x;
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapSomethingEndpoints();
app.Run();
```